# Creating an autostart application on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04, autostart, wakeup

I'm trying to setup a Python application that should automatically start when Linux boots. It should also start (unless not already running) if the computer resumes from standby mode - which is mainly the problem.

Does anybody know where to integrate these requirements?

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: Consider asking this on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a cron job every minute to detect if application running - if not start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee it's always running, have a look at `man inittab`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to autostart apps is to use Upstart.  It's way better than the cron solution above.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto